# history.go(-1) and UpdatePanel issue

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have an UpdatePanel and inside of it there is a GridView and some controls so the user can type in some searching criteria.

On the GridView there's one column with a link to another page and in that second page there is a link that does a simple history.go(-1).

The problem is that after I go back to the original search results page, the selected search criteria and the grid are empty. I need it to be in the same state as it was before leaving it.

Is there a way to acomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: How is the GridView populated? The obvious explanation is that you're losing some state when you just go back, rather than enter the page with the UpdatePanel. How about saving that state to the Session?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ASP.NET AJAX History support to maintain state across asynchronous postbacks. You're getting the original state because to the browser, that is what it should be. Dynamic updates to the DOM aren't seen as navigation events. But there is a technique that uses the url's #hash to manually create states, and thats what AJAX History is all about.

This looks like a decent article on it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488548.aspx